# Which directory to save files to, according to Apple guidelines?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, appstore-approval, file-management

I am writing an app that will save a text file to the device, like a shopping cart.

So it will be needed only while using the app.

Now, there are many directorys in the tutorials around the web, but nobody says which directory I can save files into and pass Apple's guidelines.

On my device, I save the files to the `NSDocumentDirectory` like this:

```
NSArray *pfad = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *dokumente = [pfad objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dateiname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/warenkorb.txt", dokumente];
```

Does anybody know if this will pass the review from Apple and be able to go to the App Store?

Comment: Please write your code in English, most people won't be able to understand your German variable names. Also, I'd recommend that you use stringByAppendingPathComponent: instead of stringWithFormat: for concatenating paths.

Answer (score 3):

Document directory is standard and will be accepted by Apple. But it might be better to use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` to form the full path.

```
NSString *dateiname = [dokumente stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"warenkorb.txt"];
```

Answer (score 1):

See [A Few Important Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12) to choose an appropriate directory to store your files. In your case it sounds like you want to use `tmp` rather than `Documents` since there's not need for these files to persist between launches of the application or be backed up when the device is synched.

See [Getting Paths to Standard Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6) for the suggested way to locate those directories. In this case you probably want to use [NSTemportaryDirectory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSTemporaryDirectory).